# Debugging Issues, Unsure how to fix

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment for my class and unfortunately fried my brain trying to debug the last few lines (69-84). If anyone could give me a hand that would be great!

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JInsurance extends JFrame implements ItemListener 
{
   final int hmoCOST = 200;
   final int ppoCOST = 600;
   final int dentalCOST = 75;
   final int visionCOST = 20;
   int totalCost = 0;
   int grandTotal = totalCost;

   JCheckBox hmoBox = new JCheckBox("HMO cost per month is $" + hmoCOST, false);
   JCheckBox ppoBox = new JCheckBox("PPO cost per month is $" + ppoCOST, false);
   JCheckBox dentalBox = new JCheckBox("Dental coverage is an additional $" + dentalCOST, false);
   JCheckBox visionBox = new JCheckBox("Vision coverage is an additional $" + visionCOST, false);

   JLabel selectLabel = new JLabel("Select additional coverage");
   JLabel selectPrice = new JLabel("The cost for your additional coverage is ");
   JTextField totalPrice = new JTextField(5);
   JLabel optionExplainLabel = new JLabel("The total cost is $ " + totalCost + ".");
   JLabel optionExplainLabel2 = new JLabel("Check the options you want.");

   public JInsurance()
   {
      super("Insurance Calculator");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      add(selectLabel);
      add(optionExplainLabel);
      add(optionExplainLabel2);
      add(hmoBox);
      add(ppoBox);
      add(dentalBox);
      add(visionBox);
      add(selectLabel);
      add(totalPrice);

      totalPrice.setText("$" + totalCost);
      hmoBox.addItemListener(this);
      ppoBox.addItemListener(this); 
      dentalBox.addItemListener(this);
      visionBox.addItemListener(this);
    }
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
   {
      Object source = event.getSource();
      int select = event.getStateChange();

      if(source == hmoBox)
      if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
      grandTotal += hmoCOST;
      else
      grandTotal -= hmoCOST;
      else if(source == ppoBox)
      {
      if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
      grandTotal += ppoCOST;
      else
      grandTotal -= ppoCOST;
      }
      else 
      if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
      grandTotal += dentalCOST;
      else
      grandTotal -= dentalCOST;
      }
      else
      if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
      grandTotal += visionCOST;
      else
      grandTotal -= visionCOST;
      totalCost.setText("$" + grandTotal);
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      JInsurance aFrame = new JInsurance();
        final int WIDTH = 450;
        final int HEIGHT = 400;
        aFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        aFrame.setVisible(true);
      }
}
}
```

And this is my **Error**

> JInsurance.java:69: error: illegal start of type
>         else
>         ^ JInsurance.java:69: error: ';' expected
>         else
>             ^ JInsurance.java:70: error: illegal start of type
>         if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
>           ^ JInsurance.java:70: error: ';' expected
>         if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
>                  ^ JInsurance.java:70: error:  expected
>         if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
>                                        ^ JInsurance.java:71: error:  expected
>         grandTotal += visionCOST;
>                                 ^ JInsurance.java:72: error: illegal start of type
>         else
>         ^ JInsurance.java:72: error: ';' expected
>         else
>             ^ JInsurance.java:73: error: illegal start of type
>         grandTotal -= visionCOST;
>                    ^ JInsurance.java:74: error:  expected
>         totalCost.setText("$" + grandTotal);
>                          ^ JInsurance.java:74: error: illegal start of type
>         totalCost.setText("$" + grandTotal);
>                           ^ JInsurance.java:74: error: ')' expected
>         totalCost.setText("$" + grandTotal);
>                              ^ JInsurance.java:74: error: ';' expected
>         totalCost.setText("$" + grandTotal);
>                                ^ JInsurance.java:74: error: illegal start of type
>         totalCost.setText("$" + grandTotal);
>                                           ^ JInsurance.java:74: error:  expected
>         totalCost.setText("$" + grandTotal);
>                                            ^ JInsurance.java:74: error: ';' expected
>         totalCost.setText("$" + grandTotal);
>                                             ^ JInsurance.java:84: error: class, interface, or enum expected } ^ 17 errors

Comment: Are you trying to define public static void main(String[] args) within another function? Check where the closing bracket of the previous function is.

Comment: Looks like you have too many braces in places. Use an IDE to find the matching braces. `SO` is not a debugging service. Closing due to typo errors...

Comment: Format your code to be human readable and you, as a human, may have more success reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below it shall fix your issue

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JInsurance extends JFrame implements ItemListener 
{
   final int hmoCOST = 200;
   final int ppoCOST = 600;
   final int dentalCOST = 75;
   final int visionCOST = 20;
   int totalCost = 0;
   int grandTotal = totalCost;

   JCheckBox hmoBox = new JCheckBox("HMO cost per month is $" + hmoCOST, false);
   JCheckBox ppoBox = new JCheckBox("PPO cost per month is $" + ppoCOST, false);
   JCheckBox dentalBox = new JCheckBox("Dental coverage is an additional $" + dentalCOST, false);
   JCheckBox visionBox = new JCheckBox("Vision coverage is an additional $" + visionCOST, false);

   JLabel selectLabel = new JLabel("Select additional coverage");
   JLabel selectPrice = new JLabel("The cost for your additional coverage is ");
   JTextField totalPrice = new JTextField(5);
   JLabel optionExplainLabel = new JLabel("The total cost is $ " + totalCost + ".");
   JLabel optionExplainLabel2 = new JLabel("Check the options you want.");

   public JInsurance()
   {
      super("Insurance Calculator");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      add(selectLabel);
      add(optionExplainLabel);
      add(optionExplainLabel2);
      add(hmoBox);
      add(ppoBox);
      add(dentalBox);
      add(visionBox);
      add(selectLabel);
      add(totalPrice);

      totalPrice.setText("$" + totalCost);
      hmoBox.addItemListener(this);
      ppoBox.addItemListener(this); 
      dentalBox.addItemListener(this);
      visionBox.addItemListener(this);
    }
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
   {
      Object source = event.getSource();
      int select = event.getStateChange();

      if(source == hmoBox)
      if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
      grandTotal += hmoCOST;
      else
      grandTotal -= hmoCOST;
      else if(source == ppoBox)
      {
      if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
      grandTotal += ppoCOST;
      else
      grandTotal -= ppoCOST;
      }
      else 
      if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
      grandTotal += dentalCOST;
      else
      grandTotal -= dentalCOST;
      }
      else
      if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
      grandTotal += visionCOST;
      else
      grandTotal -= visionCOST;
      totalCost.setText("$" + grandTotal);
}      
public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      JInsurance aFrame = new JInsurance();
        final int WIDTH = 450;
        final int HEIGHT = 400;
        aFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        aFrame.setVisible(true);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move your `main` method out of your `itemStateChanged` method.